# Почему не работает плагин из footer.php

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

Есть такой плагин - https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/paginator/

Пробовал менять тут `add_action('wp_head', 'paginator_sources');` на `wp_footer` - не работает.
Вставляешь напрямую в Футер - не работает.

Всяко перепробовал, работает только при запуске в HEAD

Смотрел в разметке страницы - получается, что когда запускаешь в футере не загружается скрипт который находится в `paginator.php`.

Вопрос: Почему? и что сделать чтоб заработал в Футере?

Вот код из paginator.php :

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Paginator
Plugin URI: http://dzhus.com/development/paginator/
Description: Adds "paginator3000" paging navigation to your WordPress blog.
Version: 0.2.4
Author: dzhus
Author URI: http://blog.dzhus.com
*/


/*  
    Copyright 2008  Olzhas Murtazin  (email : dzhusi@gmail.com)

    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
    Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
*/

# Function: Paginator Option Menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'paginator_menu');
function paginator_menu() {
    if (function_exists('add_options_page')) {
        add_options_page(__('Paginator', 'paginator'), __('Paginator', 'paginator'), 'manage_options', 'paginator/options.php') ;
    }
}

# Function: Paginator skin and javascript
add_action('wp_head', 'paginator_sources');
function paginator_sources() {
    echo "\n".'<!-- Start Of Script Generated By Paginator 0.2.4 -->'."\n";
    if(@file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH.'/paginator3000.css')) {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/paginator3000.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />'."\n";
    } else {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.get_option('siteurl').'/wp-content/plugins/paginator/skin/paginator3000.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />'."\n";
    }
    echo('<script type="text/javascript" src="'.get_option('siteurl').'/wp-content/plugins/paginator/js/paginator3000.js" ></script>'."\n");
    echo '<!-- End Of Script Generated By Paginator 0.2.4 -->'."\n";
}

function get_pagenum_link_without_queries() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $request = remove_query_arg( 'paged' );
    $home_root = parse_url(get_option('home'));
    $home_root = ( isset($home_root['path']) ) ? $home_root['path'] : '';
    $home_root = preg_quote( trailingslashit( $home_root ), '|' );
    $request = preg_replace('|^'. $home_root . '|', '', $request);
    $request = preg_replace('|^/+|', '', $request);

    if ( !$wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() || is_admin() ) {
        $base = trailingslashit( get_bloginfo( 'home' ) );
        $result = add_query_arg( 'paged', '=', $base . $request);
        $result = apply_filters('get_pagenum_link', $result);
    } else {
        $qs_regex = '|\?.*?$|';
        preg_match( $qs_regex, $request, $qs_match );
        if ( !empty( $qs_match[0] ) ) {
            $request = preg_replace( $qs_regex, '', $request );
        }
        $request = preg_replace( '|page/\d+/?$|', '', $request);
        $request = preg_replace( '|^index\.php|', '', $request);
        $request = ltrim($request, '/');

        $base = trailingslashit( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) );

        if ( $wp_rewrite->using_index_permalinks())
            $base .= 'index.php/';
        $request = ( ( !empty( $request ) ) ? trailingslashit( $request ) : $request ) . user_trailingslashit( 'page/' , 'paged' );
        $result = $base . $request ;
        $result = apply_filters('get_pagenum_link', $result);
        if ($result[strlen($result)-1]!="/")
            $result = $result . '/';
    }
    return $result;
}

function get_pagenum_link_query() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $request = remove_query_arg( 'paged' );
    $home_root = parse_url(get_option('home'));
    $home_root = ( isset($home_root['path']) ) ? $home_root['path'] : '';
    $home_root = preg_quote( trailingslashit( $home_root ), '|' );
    $request = preg_replace('|^'. $home_root . '|', '', $request);
    $request = preg_replace('|^/+|', '', $request);
    if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() && !is_admin() ) {
        $qs_regex = '|\?.*?$|';
        preg_match( $qs_regex, $request, $qs_match );

        if ( !empty( $qs_match[0] ) ) {
            $query_string = $qs_match[0];
        } else {
            $query_string = '';
        }
        $result = $query_string ;
    }
    $result = apply_filters('get_pagenum_link', $result);

    return $result;
}

# Function: Create Paginator
function wp_paginator() {
    global $wp_query;
    if (!is_single()) {
        $paged = intval(get_query_var('paged'));
        $cat = (intval(get_query_var('cat'))) ? ('cat='. intval(get_query_var('cat')) . '&') : '';
        $paginator_options = get_option('paginator_options');
        $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        $pages_to_show = intval($paginator_options['num_pages']);
        $display_total=intval($paginator_options['display_total']);
        $curr_url = clean_url(get_pagenum_link_without_queries());
        $curr_query = get_pagenum_link_query();
        if(empty($paged) || $paged == 0 || $paged < 0) {
            $paged = 1;
        }
        echo('<div class="paginator" id="paginator"></div>');
        if($display_total==1){
            echo('<div class="paginator_pages">'.$max_page.' pages</div>');
        }
        echo(
            '<script type="text/javascript">
                if(navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
                    var prevonload=window.onload;
                    if(typeof window.onload!="function"){
                        window.onload=function(){
                            pag = new Paginator("paginator",' . $wp_query->max_num_pages . ',' . $pages_to_show . ',' . $paged . ',"' . $curr_url . '","' . $curr_query . '");                      }
                    }else{
                        window.onload=function(){
                            prevonload();
                            pag = new Paginator("paginator",' . $wp_query->max_num_pages . ',' . $pages_to_show . ',' . $paged . ',"' . $curr_url . '","' . $curr_query . '");
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    pag = new Paginator("paginator",' . $wp_query->max_num_pages . ',' . $pages_to_show . ',' . $paged . ',"' . $curr_url . '","' . $curr_query . '");
                }
            </script>');
    }
}
```

Comment: а вы в шаблоне страницы, на которой должен выводиться paginator или в подключаемом на ней `footer.php` вызываете функцию `wp_footer()`?

Comment: функция wp_footer стоит в footer.php и скрипты все загружаются и пагинатор тоже загружается. Но на сайте не отображается. выводится только когда в Хеаде расположен.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы заработал в футере, нужно правильно скрипты и стили подгружать, а не так, как это реализовано сейчас в плагине. 
Используйте функции `wp_enqueue_script` и `wp_enqueue_style` вместо `echo`. 
Например, вам нужно заменить строчку

`echo('<script type="text/javascript" src="'.get_option('siteurl').'/wp-content/plugins/paginator/js/paginator3000.js" ></script>'."\n");`

на

`wp_enqueue_script('paginator', get_option('siteurl').'/wp-content/plugins/paginator/js/paginator3000.js', '1.0', true);`

Последний параметр функции `wp_enqueue_script` указывает, что скрипт нужно подгружать в футере. Только `wp_enqueue_script` привязывается к другом экшену - к `wp_enqueue_scripts`, а не к `wp_head`. Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC/wp_enqueue_script)